# Indexing into an array using a variable in bash/expect

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, tcl, expect

Simple script that does not work as expected. I have spent hours of hairpulling trying discover the right combination of escaping and quoting to make it work, but I have not yet succeeded.

I have an array in K that I want to loop through from an embedded expect script.

```
send_user '${list[4]}'
```

works as expected, printing the fourth element of the array on the console.

Looping the statements:

```
incr i 1
send_user "\$i"
```

work as expected, printing an incrementing interger value *12345...* etc.

But, here's the trick.

```
send_user "${list[$i]}"
```

does NOT work. No matter what the value of `$i`, it always returns the first array element, I cannot loop thru the array.

Yes, I know about escaping the `$` with a backslash, and the difference between the effects of single quotes and double quotes, etc. I have tried every combination. Like I said, hours and hours. I either get an error, nothing, or the first element of the array (as in the example) without regard to the actual value of `$i`.

I also tried moving the array directly into the expect script portion, both as an associative array and as a list. Nada. The problem is not reading the data in the array, it is retrieving that array or list data inside the embedded expect code using a variable as opposed to a discrete number.

Before abandoning this approach and rewriting a long and complicated test tool in another way, I thought I would appeal to the assembled multitudes.

I am embedding a demonstrative test script below.

Thanks to all for any suggestions.

Nathan

```
$ cat test24.sh
list=(zero one two three four)

expect <<- EXPECT_DONE

exp_internal 1

send_user '${list[4]}'

set i 0
send_user "\$i"

send_user "${list[$i]}"
incr i 1
send_user "\$i"
send_user "$list[$i]"
incr i 1
send_user "\$i"
send_user "${list[ "$i" ]}"
incr i 1
send_user "\$i"
send_user ${list[$i]}
incr i 1
send_user "\$i"
send_user "${list[$i]}"
send_user ${list[4]}
send_user "\n"

EXPECT_DONE

echo "Script done."


$ ./test24.sh
'four'0zero1zero2zero3zero4zerofour
Script done.
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus Most of this "shell" script is just an embedded Tcl script.

Comment: @Nathan You have a typo; you use `$list[i]`, not `${list[i]}`, at one point. This is equivalent to `${list[0]}[i]`, that is, the first element of the array followed by the literal string `[i]`.

Comment: (Not that the typo matters, because you are trying to index the shell array with a Tcl variable.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that any expansions of the *shell* array have to occur before the Tcl code starts executing, and you are trying to index the shell array with a Tcl variable. It's better to pass the values in the array as *arguments* to the Tcl script, rather than dynamically generating the script with embedded references to the array. This lets you single-quote the here document to avoid any additional escaping inside the script as well.

```
expect -f - "${list[@]}" <<- 'EXPECT_DONE'

exp_internal 1

send_user [lindex argv 4]

set i 0
send_user "$i"

send_user [lindex argv $i]
incr i 1
send_user $i
send_user [lindex argv $i]
incr i 1
send_user $i
send_user [lindex argv $i]
incr i 1
send_user $i
send_user [lindex argv $i]
incr i 1
send_user $i
send_user [lindex argv $i]
send_user [lindex argv 4]
send_user "\n"

EXPECT_DONE
```

(Apologies for any errors in the Tcl script; it's been a few decades since I've written any Tcl code.)

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding when/where expansion happens.

```
incr i 1
```

tells expect to add 1 to its own variable `i`.
However the shell variable `i` never sees this.

Similarly:

```
send_user "${list[$i]}"
```

is expanded by the shell before expect sees the command. The shell has no variable named `i` so `$i` expands to `0` (technically to nothing, but when used as a list subscript it will be treated as 0) and `${list[0]}` becomes `zero`. Expect receives:

```
send_user "zero"
```

One possible way to restructure your code might be to move all the processing inside the expect. Note the single-quoting of `'EXPECT_DONE'` so that the shell doesn't change any of the input:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<- 'EXPECT_DONE'

    set list [list zero one two three four]

    exp_internal 1

    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]} {incr i} {
        send_user "$i"
        send_user [lindex $list $i]
    }

    send_user "\n"

EXPECT_DONE

echo "Script done."
```

Another is to move all the processing into bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    list=(zero one two three four)

    echo "exp_internal 1"

    i=0
    while [[ $i -le ${#list} ]]; do
        echo "send_user \"$i\""
        echo "send_user \"${list[$i]}\""
        : $((i++))
    done

    echo "send_user \"\\n\""

} | expect

echo "Script done."
```

Comment: There is no shell variable i. i only exists in the expect portion. This is a very long and complex bash script with just a little bit of expect, which I distilled down to a bare essential example for posting. Perhaps I made mistakes in doing so, but other than the array, the expect makes no use of anything from bash, and the array is read-only, it passes nothing back.

Comment: The first sample above does seem at first blush to accomplish what I want, although translating the sample code back into the big script may yet reveal problems. I had previously tried this, moving the array into a list inside expect and ran into other problems. Thanks for the assist, I will work on this. It looks promising.

Comment: Per chepner's answer, you could invoke expect with the  bash list as arguments, then the tcl list `argv` will contain the elements. Or you could `{ echo "set list [list ${list[@]}]"; cat <<- 'EOD' ... } | expect` to turn the bash array into a tcl list. (although watch out for special characters in the elements)